# Convert google chart QRcode response to image using CURL GET request

Tags: php, rest, api, curl, google-visualization

**I am trying to get QRCode as a response using Google api that returns in image/png format**

Below is my code

```
  // Get CURL resource
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER =>array('Content-type: image/png'),
    CURLOPT_URL => $response,//$response will have url
));
// Send the request & save response to $resp
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
echo "$resp"
// Close request to clear up some resources
curl_close($curl);
```

But getting response in below format

```
   ���c�bKGD��������IDATx���͎�0@�P���r��
    �
  ���mf�AWV?����~�"�u��Q%䕐WB^  y%䕐WB^  y%䕐WB^  y%䕐WB^  y%䕐WB^  y?
  �_�m���|��f�ݟ1��9��
    y%䕐WBބqfg���c�����eG�oZ���J�+!o�8�s�?�)�x`�k$����V!
    ����J�[>άs�ٙ�k�J�+!��<x�95�JO7�B^   y%䕐�|�Y7)�\����i�O��WB^    
    y%��g.{,hg��IwчZ���J�+!o{ڹ�Y�v��:�B^ y%䕐7a��x��KB��|ꙩ�O�h�J�+!
   �����;s�hp�O}:�
   ��M��WB^    y%�-��42��x������J�+!�����{̺�/����B^   y%䕐��b��    
   �u�0}�sۭB^   y%䕐?ٴ��ԩwd2�ޙ�^%�%䕐�=;j��ݑvo�_vZ���J�+!
    �Q{�ʱ��p�sۭB^   y%䕐�=q�������u�B^  y%䕐oA9Ѻ�Ǐ/TM�*䕐WB^ 
   y�3Μ:�r�кsFS�
   y%䕐WB����]�nߠ�U�+!�������׽�w�{?�*䕐WB^   y�{g�G��WB^ y%䕐WB^  y%䕐
     WB^    y%䕐WB^  y%䕐WB^  y%䕐WB�o�p% f_�IEND�B`�
```

**Friends what is mistake i've commited.? And thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 0):

Try using [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide correct content type header, otherwise the browser is displaying image data as text.

Add this before the echo:

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
```

Comment: bro i added but its not displaying...and im not displaying it in browser ..i'm integrated this within api and testing in postman ... it's returning in below format  **content-type →text/html;charset=UTF-8**

Comment: Well, the sample in your post looks like image data. So you need image/png content type if you want to display it, not text/html.